# Nhibernate QueryOver nested properties

Tags: c#, nhibernate, queryover

Is there an easy way to use QueryOver with nested properties?

For example, I try something like this;

```
// SPLAT!
session.QueryOver<SuperHero>().Where(Expression.Eq("HomeBase.Name", "Bat Cave");
```

It won't work because it 'could not resolve property 'homebase.name' of SuperHero.  That makes sense, but there is obviously some way to make this work, because if I use the older 'Query' approach I can get it to work just fine, i.e.

```
// The results I (technically) want.
sess.Query<SuperHero>().Where(x => x.HomeBase.Name == "The Bat Cave");
```

So what am I missing?  I am guessing that there is some way to combine expressions, etc. to get the nexted properties to work with QueryOver, but what are they?

Comment: You'll need to explicitly join to the `HomeBase` table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do a nested property access like that--you'll have to join to the related table:

```
session.QueryOver<SuperHero>()
    .JoinQueryOver(sh => sh.HomeBase)
        .Where(hb => hb.Name == "Bat Cave");
```

Also you don't need to use strings in your restrictions--that's one of the great advantages of using QueryOver after all.

Comment: And what if I don't know what the types of the nested properties are?

Comment: The properties are mapped right? You must have specified a data type in the mapping, unless I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: Basically I have an expression tree as input that will drive the QueryOver stuff, so I don't know what the types are without a lot of extra work.

Comment: I am also looking for the answer to this puzzle. What if the method that is going to execute the `QueryOver` (the `JoinQueryOver` respectively) receives an `Expression<>` that has to be applied to my `QueryOver<>().Where()` clause