# NHibernate and C#: error using nested properties with Criteria

Tags: c#, nhibernate, hibernate-criteria

The scenario is a MVC.NET application using NHibernate to interact with a SQL Server database.

Every NHibernate query with Criteria works fine, except for the last I have added, that give the following error:

> could not resolve property: Reading.Truck.Company.CompanyId of: ADO.Alarms

Related code is the following:

```
session = NHibernateSessionManager.Instance.GetSession();
            ICriteria criteria = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Alarms));
            criteria.Add(Expression.Eq("Reading.Truck.Company.CompanyId", companyId));

            alarmsList = criteria.List<Alarms>();
```

Nested properties are defined in related class file like this:
*Alarms.cs*

```
private AlarmsReading _Reading;  
public AlarmsReading Reading
    {
        get { return _Reading; }
        set { _Reading= value; }
    }
```

These properties are defined in mapping files like this:

*Alarms.hbm.xml*

```
<hibernate-mapping  ...>
<class name="Alarms" table="Alarms" lazy="false">
<cache usage="read-write"/>
...
<many-to-one name="Reading" class="AlarmsReading">
  <column name="Reading_Id" not-null="true"/>
</many-to-one>
...
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

All other criteria query, with other nested properties, defined same way, works fine.

Strange thing is if I use normal [IQuery](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-queryinterface) syntax with createQuery method, all works smoothly; that is:

```
session = NHibernateSessionManager.Instance.GetSession();
IQuery query = null;
query = session.CreateQuery("FROM Alarms al WHERE Reading.Truck.Company.CompanyId = (:companyId) ");
query.SetParameter("companyId", companyId);
alarmsList = query.List<Alarms>();
```

I've also find this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15296162/nhibernate-queryover-nested-properties), and I know there are various way to solve, but I'm looking for the cause of this misbehaviour.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: HQL (which is what `CreateQuery` accepts) is parsed differently than queries built using Criteria or QueryOver. In this case, the HQL query is probably expanded to 3 or 4 joins (try profiling it to see). Why doesn't Criteria support this kind of querying? The short answer is just that it wasn't designed that way.

Comment: @Andrew Thanks, it is so. I've done a further analysis and found solution [here](https://forums.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=960740).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok.
I've understood how to use Criteria properly, reading answers to [this post](https://forums.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=960740), and following [this example](http://nhibernate.info/doc/howto/various/retrieve-a-nested-component-with-criteria-api.html) on the NHibernate official site.

Dot notation with Criteria seems to work only for the components of the current object (and their properties: i.e. `Reading.ReadingId`).

If we want to reach deeper properties we would use [Associations](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-associations).

So this code works fine for my task:

```
session = NHibernateSessionManager.Instance.GetSession();
ICriteria criteria = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Alarms));
criteria.CreateCriteria("Reading").CreateCriteria("Truck")
        .Add(Expression.Eq("Company.CompanyId", companyId));

alarmsList = criteria.List<Alarms>();
```